# Ruby Magic Code using Boolean after nil check for gender

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I love ruby magic code and I want try to get value from boolean after null check without using call string again.

I have column ismale structure tinyin(Boolean) and have null

```
if null == "Unknown"
if true == "Male"
if false == "Female"
```

I have

```
@user.ismale.nil? ? "Unknown" : @user.ismale ? "Male" : "Female"
```

I dont want to call @user.ismale 2 times

```
@user.ismale.nil? ? "Unknown" : ? "Male" : "Female"
```

can I get this magic code ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `case` expression:

```
case @user.ismale
when true
  "Male"
when false
  "Female"
else
  "Unknown"
end
```

Or a hash:

```
{ true => "Male", false => "Female", nil => "Unknown" }[@user.ismale]
```

or using a fallback value:

```
{ true => "Male", false => "Female" }.fetch(@user.ismale, "Unknown")
```

Comment: wew best using hash one line. cool, thank you

Comment: @grenz consider encapsulating the logic in a method, e.g. `@user.gender` which returns `:male`, `:female` or `:unknown` / `nil` along with [I18n](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) localization to translate the symbols to `"Male"`, `"Female"` and (maybe as a fallback) `"Unknown"`.

Comment: Yes sir you are right, now I using [I18n](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) like this, en: account: gender: m: = "Male" f:"Female" n:"Unknown", using hardcode will give me a headache, Thank you very much